# Firefox. Cursor doesn't change its state on any event

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-edition

I'm having this issues with the cursor in standard Firefox and Developer Edition. I've search on internet about, and make some tweaks on config setting, but nothing seems to work for me.

Here I show a screen capture to demonstrate what's happening clearly. If I hover over a link, it do not change until I hit on the link, can't neither select a text, and so on...

[image: Firefox. Cursor doesn't change its state on any event.]

I event tried in Safe Mode, disabled all addons, etc, but the problem persists.

Here some specifications:

- Firefox 104
- Firefox Developer Edition 105
- Ubuntu 22.04
- Gnome 42.4

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Just restart my computer with the option Ubuntu on Xorg and voilà... Now I have problems with dark mode on Google, but I can live with it...